# Local notification based on geo location

Tags: ios, geolocation, notifications, mkmapview, local

My project contains a mapView with objects placed as pins in different locations.

When the user enters the region of one of these pins, I want a local notification to be triggered, telling the user that he's near by that particular object. I've had a look at the documentation, but I can't seem to work it out.

I've posted my code [here](http://pastebin.com/ytpXaCE6) if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

`MKMapView` is good at showing the user's location, but you need to use CoreLocation in order to determine if a user enters a particular region. Particularly, you'll want to look at the `-startMonitoringForRegion:` method of the `CLLocationManager` class. You should implement the `-locationManager:didEnterRegion:` delegate method from `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and fire your local notification from there.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self; 

// Create a region centered around a map pin
// You'll need to do this for every pin region you wish to monitor
CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:pinCenter 
                                                           radius:regionRadius 
                                                       identifier:yourRegionIdentifier]; 
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];

.
.
.

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = @"You entered a region"; 
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}
```

Comment: I've done this, however the didEnterRegion is not being called. What am I doing wrong? Check out my code here http://pastebin.com/uNA4fwWY